# GDAL_Translate resampling method (nearest?)

Tags: image, processing, gdal

I would like to ask a question. I'm using the gdal_translate routine available in the GDAL/OGR package. I would like to know what resampling method is applied when resizing an image.

In the new version of GDAL they allow to choose the resampling method, but in the previous version is not written anywhere! Do you have any clue? I guess they use the nearest neighbor but I'm not sure.

Thanks,
Solimyr

Answer (score 2):

The standard algorithm used by *gdal_translate* was "nearest neighbour". So far other resampling methods have only been implemented in *gdalwarp* but could not be called from *gdal_translate* directly (which uses gdalwarp for resampling procedures).

This has been asked several times on the gdal-dev mailing list - e.g. [gdal_translate -outsize resampling method?](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-September/037019.html)